# What's wrong with my implementation of SquareFreeQ?

Tags: factorization

This was a question I had last month:

> **Part A:**  Looking at the exponent of each of the elements in the list, `FactorInteger` and using `Select` construct your own variant of `SquareFreeQ`. Call it `squareFreeQ`. (You want the list of powers in `FactorInteger` to be all be 1, equivalently no power should be greater than  1 . The right `Select` evaluated on `FactorInteger` should give `{}`. Notice we only have to find one power > 1 so you will speed things up by using `Select` with an option.
>
> **Part B:** Test that your construction `squareFreeQ` and *Mathematica's* `SquareFreeQ` are identical. You can do this by selecting the integer for which `SquareFreeQ[n] != squarefreeQ[n]`. Do this on a list of $10^5$ random integers between $10^{13}$ and $10^{14}$. Tell me how long it takes to perform this test. Be prepared to wait a little while.

This is what I had for part A:

```
squareFreeQ := Select[Last /@ FactorInteger[#], # > 1 &] &
```

and for part B:

```
Timing[SquareFreeQ[#] & /@ RandomInteger[{10^13, 10^14}, 10^15]]
squareFreeQ := Select[Last /@ FactorInteger[#], # > 1 &] &
```

When I got my assignment back, it says incorrect with no explanation.
What would be the correct answer?  Please explain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming only integers will be input to squareFreeQ.

Your squareFreeQ as defined in the question does not return True or False
as does the built-in SquareFreeQ. Rather your function returns a list of
exponents, if any, which are greater than one. Hence, after selecting
exponents exceeding 1, compare the list to {}, which occurs for squarefree
numbers. The result is True or False.

```
squareFreeQ[n_Integer]:=Select[FactorInteger[n][[All,2]],#>1&]=={}
```

For Part B you could try the following, which took 27 s on my machine.
Your code as written in the question here, requests 10^15 random integers,
which might be another "incorrect" in the marker's eyes.

```
With[{r=RandomInteger[{10^13,10^14},10^5]}, 
   AbsoluteTiming[Select[r, squareFreeQ[#]=!=SquareFreeQ[#]&]]]
```

Comment: +1 and I expanded a bit on your answer (see my answer), I hope you don't mind.

Comment: No worries, expansions welcome!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what the prof was thinking, but your function is not the same as the built-in function. Here are four cases.

```
squareFreeQ := Select[Last /@ FactorInteger[#], # > 1 &] &;
{squareFreeQ[#], SquareFreeQ[#]} & /@ {10, 12, x^4 - 1, x^4 - 2 x^2 + 1}
```

They agree on the first two, but your function throws errors on the final two while SquareFreeQ says True and False respectively.

Answer (score 1):

I think that @KennyColnago is right, you need to make sure you return `True` or `False`. Additionally, in the last sentence in part A your prof is pointing out that you should use an option to **make sure [`Select`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Select.html) quits the routine as soon as a power is found**, thus you can (and possibly should) use the third argument (strictly speaking not an "option") of [`Select`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Select.html):

```
squareFreeQ := Select[Last /@ FactorInteger[#], # > 1 &, 1] == {} &
```

I am using `FactorInteger` here as your prof points out, knowing that this won't work for expressions like the ones mentioned in @bills answer.

Then for Part B, you could do either like in KennyColnago's idea:

```
With[{r=RandomInteger[{10^13,10^14},10^5]}, 
   AbsoluteTiming[Select[r, squareFreeQ[#]=!=SquareFreeQ[#]&,1]]]
```

(where we use again the 3rd argument in [`Select`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Select.html), to get the first exception only - but as we are confident, we don't really need it here. Just to illustrate the point.)

Alternatively:

```
rInts = RandomInteger[{10^13, 10^14}, 10^5];
(res1 = SquareFreeQ /@ rInts;) // AbsoluteTiming
(res2 = squareFreeQ /@ rInts;) // AbsoluteTiming
```

Both are just about the same speed, and:

```
res1 == res2
```

> `True`

Answer (score 1):

The function `squareFreeQ` returns the exponents of factorization where as the the function `SquareFreeQ` is boolean, returning true if there are no square factors, viz al exponents are 1. Although the following does not use `Select` it can perhaps be motivation for desired solution:

```
squarefreeq[u_] := And @@ (#[[2]] == 1 & /@ FactorInteger[u]);
```

Testing:

```
rand = RandomInteger[{10^13, 10^14}, 10^5];
{t0, sq} = Timing[squarefreeq /@ rand];
{t1, Sq} = Timing[SquareFreeQ /@ rand];
```

t0 13.48 seconds, t1 12.03 seconds.

```
sq==Sq
```

yields `True`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe too late to join the party, but here's is my implementation for *squareFreeQ*.

We know that a number is square-free, if its prime decomposition contains no repeated factors.
Also we've to take into account, that 1 is by convention squarefree.

We can list the first squarefree numbers using:

```
Select[Range[20], Max[Last /@ FactorInteger[#]] < 2 &]
```

and we could compare this with Sloanes sequence [A005117](http://oeis.org/A005117)

Having this, an implementation seems to be rather straight forward:

```
squareFreeQ[x_] := Max[Last /@ FactorInteger[x]] < 2

squareFreeQ[11] ==> True
squareFreeQ[12] ==> False
```

Timings are:

```
rInts = RandomInteger[{10^13, 10^14}, 10^5];
(res1 = SquareFreeQ /@ rInts;) // AbsoluteTiming
(res2 = squareFreeQ /@ rInts;) // AbsoluteTiming  

{34.255805, Null}
{39.001603, Null}
```

I'm loosing 5 seconds when compared to the internal implementation, but I'm sure that squareFreeQ could be tweaked...